# How to use the vSphere SDK for Perl with IPV6 hosts

Tags: perl, vmware, ipv6, esxi, vsphere

I'm attempting to refactor old perl code to support some new IPV6-only hosts.

In testing the basic '`connect.pl`' script, it fails with

Unsupported IP address format:

```
#/usr/lib/vmware-vcli/apps/general/connect.pl --url https://fe80::b6b5:2fff:fe5a:c5d8:443/sdk --username root --password pw
Unsupported IP address format
```

I also wrote a little test script to exercise Util::connect, and it fails in the same way.

Caveats:

I'm using `VMware-vSphere-Perl-SDK-5.1.0-780721`.

In my scenario, the `ESXi` hosts run `IPV6` only, and the guests will run `IPV4` only.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues here.

1. IPv6 literal addresses in a URL need to be in brackets.
2. Your link-local address is missing an interface identifier.

Specify the link-local address in brackets with the correct interface identifier. For example:

```
https://[fe80::b6b5:2fff:fe5a:c5d8%eth0]:443/sdk
```

Comment: No joy:   



/usr/lib/vmware-vcli/apps/general/connect.pl --url https://[fe80::b6b5:2fff:fe5a:c5d8%eth0]/sdk --username root --password pw                                             
Unsupported IP address format



#/usr/lib/vmware-vcli/apps/general/connect.pl --url "https://[fe80::b6b5:2fff:fe5a:c5d8%eth0]/sdk" --username root --password pw    
Unsupported IP address format




However, I was able to connect using pysphere and this URL format. Is there something else I should do to connect with the VSphere API?

Comment: Fix the bug in the perl script?

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer here is that, for unknown reasons, the API checks for link-local "fe80" addresses, and errors if it sees them.

connect.pl (which is sample code provided by VMware) works just fine with a global-scoped IPV6 address.